# Finding frequency distribution of unknown distribution after change in deductible

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a question I came across which I've been stuck on for quite a long time:

Losses have a Pareto distribution with α=2 and mean 1250. Initially there is an ordinary deductible of 720 per loss and no policy limit, and the frequency distribution for the number of payments has probability function $\Pr(N_d=k)=0.4−0.1k$, $k=0,1,2,3$. The deductible is then reduced but a policy limit of 8,000 is introduced so that the expected cost per loss remains the same as that before the change.

What I have done:

I have found the percentage change in the expected cost per loss to be -31.07% after the change in deductible, and now I need to find the new frequency distribution. I also calculated that the new deductible, $d^* = 385.601$.

Where I'm stuck at:

How do I find the new frequency distribution for number of payments after the reduction in deductibles? As in how do I find $\Pr(N_{d^*}=k)$ for $k=0,1,2,3$, where d* is the new deductible?

Note: I have learnt how to change the parameter for (a,b,0) class of distribution but in this case, the frequency distribution is an unknown one.

(a,b,0) distributions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28a,b,0%29_class_of_distributions

Comment: Why would changing the policy change number of accidents? These two seem independent, so you can assume distribution of the number of payments stays the same.

Comment: they arent the same as we're talking about the number of payments (not the number of accidents). When there is a deductible of 720, we only pay if the accident results in a loss above 720. Right now, the deductible is reduced from 720 to 385.601, hence we would expect more payments to occur... I'm just unsure of how to work out the probability for this

Comment: Got it. Then let $p_k$ be the probability that there are $k$ accidents total. Accidents are assumed to be independent. Since $N_d\le 3$, the only non-zero values of $p_i$ are $p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3$. Now for $k\le 3$, express $P(N_d=k)$ in terms of $p_i$'s and $\alpha=P(loss>720)$ - you'll get $4$ linear equations in $4$ variables (for example $P(N_d=2)=p_2\alpha^2+3p_3\alpha^2(1-\alpha)$). Solve for those $p_i$'s and use them to compute new distribution of payments using $\alpha' = P(loss>d^*)$ instead of $\alpha$ in the same $4$ equations since $p_i$'s stay the same.